# Mysql connector - MultipleActiveResultSets issue

Tags: c#, mysql, connector

First off, I have spent hours looking for a fix - maybe I just need another pair of eyes on this problem.

I'm currently coding a c# application for myself(Personal use). Im running the latest MySQL connector library from mysql.com

My connection string is

```
public string SQLConnection = "Server=localhost;Database=data;Uid=root;Pwd=ascent;charset=utf8;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;";
```

My issue is regarding `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` . When this is included in my SQLConnection string the MySQL library is unable to connect. View the pic below to view my findings

[image] *full image: http://i62.tinypic.com/25a57p1.png*

When `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` is removed from the connection string, I get this result

[image] *full image: http://i58.tinypic.com/2useaom.png*

I get a successful connection.

The reason for `MultipleActiveResultSets` is because I'm using 2 `MySqlDataReader` at the same time - This however can't be changed.

If anyone knows why this is failing, then please suggest your fix.

My local MySQL server version: 5.6.17

Comment: Put the line where you're creating the connection inside the try block. That's where it seems to fall, so you want to catch the exception that throws. That will probably tell you what's wrong.

Answer (score 13):

I assume MySql connector doesn't support MARS (Multiple active result sets). In such case you cannot use it at more than one place at the same time.

Comment: I have just spent the last week getting to know the MySQL wire protocol and I can confirm that this is correct; there would be no way for MySQL to support multiple active result sets. You need to either buffer your data into a list and then perform another query or open a second connection.

Comment: "mars is not available in MySQL"

I found a evidence on MySql forum https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,65931,260092

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not solved but I have found a work around.

I removed `MultipleActiveResultSets=True;` from the connection string. I then created a list where I saved the data from MySqlDataReader, I then closed the reader and reopen a new one which then I got the rest of the data from the database. Then simply merged the results together in the list.

So yeah, a temp fix.

If someone knows the proper fix then please comment, otherwise I will be using my temp fix.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

One more option which can cause a little performance hit but can be used as quick fix is to open one more connection to the database for the second reader and close it when you are done.