# retrieve data from database and insert those values to another table in database c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm getting error in connection open like "The connection is already opened". It is telling to close the opened connection of while loop(reading data from table). But any way the data's have to inserted to data base while reading. How to solve?

```
private bool iscompanyExist(string comname)
{
    string query = "select * from Ageingrpt where Companyname='" + comname + "' group by Companyname having sum(current)>0 or sum('a1-30')>0 or sum('a31-60')>0 or sum('a61-90')>0 or sum('a90g')>0 ;";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn);
    MySqlDataReader reader1;
    cnn.Open();
    reader1 = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader1.HasRows)
    {
        cnn.Close();
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        cnn.Close();
        return false;
    }
}

private void Ageingcalc()
{
    string duedate = null;
    string compname = null, outstanding = null;
    //90<
    string query = "select c.address1,sum(p.OutstandingAmt) from invoice i,payment p,customer c where p.invoiceNo=i.invoiceNo and i.cid=c.cid and p.OutstandingAmt>0 and i.dueDate<'" + DateTime.Now + "'   group by c.address1 ;";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn);
    MySqlDataReader reader;
    cnn.Open(); //open1
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        compname = reader[0].ToString();
        outstanding = reader[1].ToString();
        if (iscompanyExist(compname) == true)
        {
            cnn.Open();
            query = "update Ageingrpt set a90g='" + outstanding + "';";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn);
            MySqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // query will be executed and data saved to the db
            cnn.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            cnn.Open();
            query = "insert into Ageingrpt  values('" + compname + "',0,0,0,0,'" + outstanding + "',0); ";
            cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn);
            cmd.ExecuteReader(); // query will be executed and data saved to the db
            cnn.Close();
        }
    }

    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Why not write a simple `INSERT SELECT FROM WHERE` ? What you try will be at least 2N times slower - once for each insert and once for each "check". For 10 rows, it will be 20 times slower. For 2000, it will be 2000 times slower

Comment: when you `cnn.Open()` again in the `IF ELSE` in your `Ageingcalc()` method

Comment: You are opening the connection `cnn` again inside your while-loop

Comment: Thanks. I can understand the error.This is the scenario.  A set of data will be retrieved from invoice table in while loop nah. I have to check each record in the query which is used in while loop reader. In each record the 'company name' will be retrieved.I have to check whether the 'company' field already exit in ageingrpt table or not. if exist i have to update the record in ageingrpt table else insert that record in ageing report table. The main thing is i have to process every record retrieved in while loop. But the error is saying to close the connection opened for while loop.

Comment: if i close the while loop  connection before if condition I can only process the last record retrieved in loop nah?

Comment: I believe that you code needs only one `cnn.Open()` at the beginning and one `cnn.Close()` at the end of your Ageingcalc method. Your code should work just fine if you comment out all other lines where connection is opened or closed. I’d also suggest to `use try {...} finally {...}` block in Ageingcalc and close the connection inside the `finally` block.

Comment: Let make some cleaning here. In MySql you cannot use the same connection to serve two (or more) reader/commands. ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953560/mysql-connector-multipleactiveresultsets-issue ) You need two connections or load everything in memory in a DataTable and then process row by row that table. Of course, if possible, the first advice given to you is the most correct one to follow.

Comment: Moreover, it seems that you are using a global connection kept alongside your code and opened and closed when needed. This is another capital sin. You should create the connection when you need it and dispose it when you have done. Do not try to be smart on this point. You just disrupts the good work make for you by connection pooling

Comment: I did like u said. But I'm getting error like "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."

Comment: Thank u so much. Using DataTable is worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is worked for me.I have used DataTable to store the retrieved data.

```
 private void Ageingcalc()
            {
                string duedate = null;
                string compname = null, outstanding = null;


                //90<
                string query = "select c.address1,sum(p.OutstandingAmt) as outstanding from invoice i,payment p,customer c where p.invoiceNo=i.invoiceNo and i.cid=c.cid and p.OutstandingAmt>0 and i.dueDate<'" + DateTime.Now + "'   group by c.address1 ;";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn);
                MySqlDataReader reader;
                cnn.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                da.Dispose();
                cnn.Close();

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {

                    if (iscompanyExist(row["address1"].ToString()) == true)
                    {
                        cnn.Open();
                        MessageBox.Show(row["address1"].ToString());
                        query = "update Ageingrpt set a90g='" + row["outstanding"].ToString() + "';";
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn);
                        MySqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // query will be executed and data saved to the db
                        cnn.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cnn.Open();
                        MessageBox.Show(row["address1"].ToString());
                        query = "insert into Ageingrpt  values('" + row["address1"].ToString() + "',0,0,0,0,'" + row["outstanding"].ToString() + "',0); ";
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn);
                        MySqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // query will be executed and data saved to the db
                        cnn.Close();
                    }


                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void Ageingcalc()
            {
                string duedate = null;
                string compname = null, outstanding = null;

                //90<
                string query = "select c.address1,sum(p.OutstandingAmt) from invoice i,payment p,customer c where p.invoiceNo=i.invoiceNo and i.cid=c.cid and p.OutstandingAmt>0 and i.dueDate<'" + DateTime.Now + "'   group by c.address1 ;";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn);
                MySqlDataReader reader;
                cnn.Open();         //open1
                reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    compname = reader[0].ToString();
                    outstanding = reader[1].ToString();
                    if (iscompanyExist(compname) == true)
                    {
                        query = "update Ageingrpt set a90g='" + outstanding + "';";
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn);
                        MySqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // query will be executed and data saved to the db
                        cnn.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        query = "insert into Ageingrpt  values('" + compname + "',0,0,0,0,'" + outstanding + "',0); ";
                        cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, cnn);
                        cmd.ExecuteReader(); // query will be executed and data saved to the db
                        cnn.Close();
                    }

                }
                cnn.Close();
            }


once connection is open and need to close it..we should not open again..
```