# C# Using multiple MySQL connection or put queries in queue to execute respectively

Tags: c#, mysql, database-connection

I have a client/server app and my server stores data in a `MySQL database`, currently I have made a connection and I do queries without queue or something. I don't think this is a good solution for this, because when a `MySQLDataReader` opens another one can't be execute at the same time and first one must be closed. I think I have two options, either make a connection by every `DataReader` or put my queries in a queue to execute them one by one.

I want to know which one is the best or is there any way or something to prevent errors and exception which causes this error

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

This is how currently I am doing queries. I first get the main connection and do queries. it my causes above error.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username";

ServerModel.Database.CheckConnection(); // Get the main connection
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, ServerModel.Database);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

UserStatus userStatus;
using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (dataReader.Read())
    {
        ...
        dataReader.Close();
        return userStatus;
    }
}
```

To note that this server may do thousands of queries at moment. think about a chat server.

Comment: SO basics, always present code with question

Comment: With SQL Server you would need to put `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` in the connection string, but this certainly wasn't supported by Mysql a little while ago (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953560/mysql-connector-multipleactiveresultsets-issue)  So unless support has been added since it looks like you'll simply have to either have multiple connections or manage a queue of statements as you suggest...

Comment: @GPW To note that I may have thousands of queries at one minute. Which one is better ?

Comment: Opening connections is a relatively expensive operation, but if your code is asynchronous (e.g. a web API that may receive multiple concurrent requests) then having to queue up all your operations may become a bottleneck... maybe some combination of the two - some sort of connection pool with up to X connections that each have a queue...  I suspect there will be a good solution out there to this..

Comment: Have you considered using an ORM like Entity Framework?  I would assume those have all solved this problem as otherwise they'd probably get pretty unworkable quickly.

Comment: Think about storing a messenger's chats, every time a text message packet received from any client it must be store and send response whenever that message stores. To note that, every packet received will go into a queue and I do queries on that queue, my intend was to put queries executes into another queue for executing queries.

I want to know opening multiple connection can cause a timeout or being sent a little earlier ?

Answer (score -1):

In this case please don't use the **using** block, I hope below approach will work fine.

```
    string query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = @username";

    ServerModel.Database.CheckConnection(); // Get the main connection
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, ServerModel.Database);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);

    UserStatus userStatus;

    MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    if (dataReader.Read())
        {
            ...
            dataReader.Close();
            return userStatus;
        }
```