# Exception - "This MySqlConnection is already in use" when using MYSql server. However the same Linq query works fine with MS SQL Server

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I am developing a Quality Assurance Application using the .NET Core framework (5.0). Initially, I have used MS SQL Server DB and it was working fine. However, now due to requirement change, I have now moved to MYSQL Server.

I have successfully integrated the database using the code-first approach (Entity framework). Also, I am using the NuGet package **Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql** and everything works just fine except the below-mentioned Linq query where I am getting an exception - **This MySqlConnection is already in use**.

```
public List<ErrorMessage> GetErrorMessage(int productId)
{
    List<ErrorMessage> localList = new List<ErrorMessage>();
    var product = _db.Products.Where(a => a.ProductId == productId).FirstOrDefault();
    if (product != null)
    {

        var products = _db.Products
            .Where(q => q.ProductName.ToLower() == product.ProductName.ToLower()).Select(e => e.ProductId);
        foreach (var item in products)
        {
            var errormessage = _db.ErrorMessageTracks.Where(q => q.ProductId == item).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage);
            foreach (var msg in errormessage)
            {
                if (!localList.Select(q => q.ErrorMessageId).Contains(msg.ErrorMessageId))
                {

                    localList.Add(msg);
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return localList;
}
```

I have referred to other similar questions but I couldn't resolve the issue as I am not sure how to close the SQL connection as I am using Linq Query and not the actual SQL Join. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This smells like an issue outside of this method - how do you instantiate your DB context and is there possibly an async method being called and not awaited in the call stack above?

Comment: Perhaps this is related to the inability of MySql .NET Connector to support MultipleActiveResultSets. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953560/mysql-connector-multipleactiveresultsets-issue

Comment: You could check if adding a .ToList() at the end of the _var products_ initialization change something

Comment: @Steve,  I have added ToList() and it worked. Thank you.  :)

Comment: However, measure the performances. The ToList materialize the query and you get back the whole set of data while the previous version uses a record by record approach. Perhaps you could create a JOIN between the two queries and avoid the two queries at all.

Comment: I have 3 tables - Products, Errors, and ProductErrorTrack (It is a reference table that has FK of Product and Error). Do you think joining them instead of iteration with Linq (what I used) would be a better approach?

Comment: The point is to minimize database access. If there is a way to create a Linq to Sql expression that do all the work in a single call using joins then it should give you better performances. However performances needs to be measured. Sometime the extra work doesn't pay off enough, sometime you have big gains. If your code is acceptable as is then no need to change. It is your call.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Thanks for the information. I will have a look. Have a good day Steve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `ToList()` at the end of the linq query,it should solve the problem:

```cs
var products = _db.Products.Where(q => q.ProductName.ToLower() == product.ProductName.ToLower())
                           .Select(e => e.ProductId).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding `Tolist()` to get the *products* for the the outer `for` will execute the query immediately and allow the connection to be available for the inner `for` to get the *items*.

Comment: this might be better posted as comment